# How do I set up a bridge network with KVM where the virtual guest is acting as DHCP server?

Tags: networking, kvm, dhcp, bridge

I want to run a virtualized pfSense server on a KVM host (Debian 10) along with some other virtualized servers. I have a NIC expansion card that I want to passthrough to pfSense. The host machine will not be connected directly to the network (it will get its connection through the bridge from pfSense.) Ideally I would like the host to get it's IP/config from pfSense using DHCP. The issue is that this creates a bit of a dependency loop, because in order to start the VM the bridge needs to be up, but in order for the bridge to go up it needs to reach the DHCP server, which is the VM...

I need to be a able to bring the bridge up and have it hold off on acquiring DHCP lease until the server has started up. What's a sensible way of handling this?

Comment: Have the host use a static IP so it won't depend on the VM, that's the only sensible way I can think of.

Comment: @A.B I'd rather not do that. Even though this computer is hosting the VM's I'd rather it be treated like any other computer on the network, with no special static IP exceptions.